# FFPROBE - "Unspecified pixel format"

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe, pixelformat

I have a bunch of MP4's that were pulled off an Android phone that will not play. By all accounts, they "appear" to be fine but there's obviously an issue. I've tried converting them with Handbrake, Avidemux and FFMPEG with no success. I believe the videos are missing the pixel format but I'm not certain.

I've tried various ffmpeg commands with the `-pix_fmt`, `-analyzeduration` and `-probsize` and nothing seems to be working.

Below is a screenshot of an ffprobe command on one of the problem files.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Thanx in advance.

When I attempt to use ffprobe to view the file details I get the following:

```
ffprobe -i 2017_0183.mp4
ffprobe version 2022-01-03-git-68d0a7e446-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
  libavcodec     59. 15.102 / 59. 15.102
  libavformat    59. 12.100 / 59. 12.100
  libavdevice    59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavfilter     8. 21.100 /  8. 21.100
  libswscale      6.  1.102 /  6.  1.102
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (0 > 270009).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 270013
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (0 > 270009).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1680192122 > 75205).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 75209
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1680192122 > 75205).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1450040905 > 63809).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 63813
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1450040905 > 63809).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1400530058 > 67717).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 67721
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1400530058 > 67717).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-68954687 > 65203).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 65207
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-68954687 > 65203).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1078623335 > 70021).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 70025
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1078623335 > 70021).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-209073634 > 50506).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 50510
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-209073634 > 50506).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1373066907 > 78417).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 78421
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1373066907 > 78417).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-973895533 > 62339).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 62343
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-973895533 > 62339).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (179652617 > 67686).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 67690
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (179652617 > 67686).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1264548781 > 54817).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 54821
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1264548781 > 54817).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (52871066 > 64426).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 64430
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (52871066 > 64426).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (152767522 > 64251).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 64255
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (152767522 > 64251).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1596715801 > 63904).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 63908
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1596715801 > 63904).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1009260136 > 68878).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 68882
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1009260136 > 68878).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-815491385 > 61279).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 61283
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-815491385 > 61279).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (317253157 > 60677).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 60681
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (317253157 > 60677).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (107431559 > 83671).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 83675
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (107431559 > 83671).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-791441063 > 44889).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 44893
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-791441063 > 44889).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1630609819 > 71128).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 71132
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1630609819 > 71128).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-652421078 > 61815).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 61819
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-652421078 > 61815).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-2009877451 > 68324).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 68328
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-2009877451 > 68324).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1864560497 > 58368).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 58372
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1864560497 > 58368).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-2101929602 > 57153).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 57157
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-2101929602 > 57153).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1464745827 > 75056).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 75060
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1464745827 > 75056).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (2034160309 > 43046).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 43050
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (2034160309 > 43046).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1321345220 > 76687).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 76691
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1321345220 > 76687).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1399562376 > 59244).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 59248
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1399562376 > 59244).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (2034358897 > 50105).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 50109
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (2034358897 > 50105).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[aac @ 00000253bf8a5180] Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 00000253bf8a5180] Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 00000253bf8a5180] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1682505937 > 78143).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 78147
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1682505937 > 78143).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-334926039 > 169854).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 169858
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-334926039 > 169854).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1154639859 > 73640).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 73644
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1154639859 > 73640).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1321074045 > 53484).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 53488
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1321074045 > 53484).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1959389215 > 91045).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 91049
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1959389215 > 91045).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1629897619 > 68170).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 68174
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1629897619 > 68170).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-2049516629 > 76369).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 76373
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-2049516629 > 76369).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (381499616 > 118402).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 118406
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (381499616 > 118402).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (389023451 > 73373).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 73377
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (389023451 > 73373).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-403791192 > 60482).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 60486
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-403791192 > 60482).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1997026367 > 54895).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 54899
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1997026367 > 54895).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-490366417 > 62454).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 62458
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-490366417 > 62454).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1596159668 > 70344).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 70348
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1596159668 > 70344).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1540094197 > 59550).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 59554
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1540094197 > 59550).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-261615060 > 55787).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 55791
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-261615060 > 55787).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (245201034 > 63892).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 63896
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (245201034 > 63892).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1427389036 > 60433).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 60437
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1427389036 > 60433).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-2100910052 > 60698).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 60702
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-2100910052 > 60698).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1325452001 > 71095).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 71099
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1325452001 > 71095).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1070844579 > 61122).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 61126
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1070844579 > 61122).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (635190275 > 57524).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 57528
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (635190275 > 57524).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1205276538 > 64981).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 64985
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1205276538 > 64981).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (562605283 > 86834).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 86838
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (562605283 > 86834).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (853813753 > 51856).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 51860
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (853813753 > 51856).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1173248275 > 68320).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 68324
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1173248275 > 68320).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-499209399 > 70764).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 70768
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-499209399 > 70764).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (996729301 > 62007).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 62011
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (996729301 > 62007).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1965543957 > 61779).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 61783
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1965543957 > 61779).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (341017654 > 62982).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 62986
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (341017654 > 62982).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1191243776 > 49466).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 49470
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1191243776 > 49466).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (945590663 > 91565).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 91569
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (945590663 > 91565).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-613335061 > 207634).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 207638
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-613335061 > 207634).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1227809132 > 61106).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 61110
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1227809132 > 61106).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-434107277 > 54670).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 54674
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-434107277 > 54670).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (123794999 > 81654).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 81658
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (123794999 > 81654).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-448644632 > 64954).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 64958
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-448644632 > 64954).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1179949705 > 73074).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 73078
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-1179949705 > 73074).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1454361779 > 59571).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 59575
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (1454361779 > 59571).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (359160100 > 70654).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 70658
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (359160100 > 70654).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-325884104 > 53875).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] missing picture in access unit with size 53879
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Invalid NAL unit size (-325884104 > 53875).
[h264 @ 00000253bf8a1280] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000253bde38c80] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 16924 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2017_0183.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-09-16T23:13:38.000000Z
    com.android.version: 7.0
  Duration: 00:00:24.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17375 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 16924 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.80 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-09-16T23:13:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-09-16T23:13:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The "unspecified pixel format" is a consequence, not a cause. It can't figure out the pixfmt because it can't parse an [SPS](https://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/the-h-264-sequence-parameter-set) out of the H.264 datastream, and it can't do *that* because the file is too corrupt for it to read the framing and find any actual video packets (as indicated by all of the "Invalid NAL unit size"). You're not going to fix this with any conventional tools, and probably not at all.